Express.js redirecting to incorrect URL when using custom URL scheme
I'm developing a Node.js application using Express.js, and I'm encountering an issue with URL redirection when using a custom URL scheme. Here's my setup:
I have an environment variable set up like this:
APP_URL=myapp://confirm

And here's my Express.js route for user verification:
router.get('/api/verify', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { token } = req.query;
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Verification token is required' });
    }

    const result = await verifyUser(token);

    if (result.verified) {
      const redirectUrl = `${process.env.APP_URL}?email=${encodeURIComponent(result.email)}`;
      res.redirect(302, redirectUrl);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found or already verified' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error verifying user:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

The problem is that when I try to redirect to my custom URL scheme, Express.js is appending the current host and path to the URL. So instead of redirecting to:
myapp://confirm?email=user@example.com

It's redirecting to:
http://localhost:3000/v1/api/myapp://confirm?email=user@example.com

This results in a "Cannot GET /v1/api/myapp://confirm" error.
How can I modify my Express.js route to correctly redirect to my custom URL scheme without prepending the current host and path?
The deep link url is supposed to launch an android app instead of making an api request that does not exist.

In express when you use res.redirect(302, redirectUrl); it assume that redirectUrl is a relative-path and appends it to the current domain(http://localhost:3000 in your case).
To redirect to a custom protocol you can do this instead.
if (result.verified) {
  const redirectUrl = `${process.env.APP_URL}?email=${encodeURIComponent(result.email)}`;
  res.status(302).header('Location', redirectUrl).end();
}

You can get more detailed information about the res.redirect() here in the official docs.
Try this, it will work for sure.
